# Tree Set behaves differently but hash set doesn't in case of custom object

Tags: java, collections

In below created code have  Employee class  with attributes Id and Name,Created 3 objects of Employee class e1,e2,e3 with respective name attribute a,b,a. when I add these object in hash set the size shows 3 but on same while in Tree Set it show size 2 even i am not overriding the hash code and equals method.

```
    Emplyoee class.............................


        package collection.core.concept;

        public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{

            private int id;
            private String name;

            public int getId() {
                return id;
            }
            public void setId(int id) {
                this.id = id;
            }
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }
            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

           @Override
           public int compareTo(Employee o) {
            if(this.name.equal(o.getName()){
               return 0;
            }else{
              return 1;
              }
           }
            @Override
            public String toString(){
            return name;

            }
    }

    main class...............................................
    public class CustomTreeSetSorting {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Employee e1 = new Employee();
            e1.setId(1);
            e1.setName("alok");
            Employee e2 = new Employee();
            e2.setId(2);
            e2.setName("vaibhav");
            Employee e3 = new Employee();
            e3.setId(3);
            e3.setName("alok");


            Set<Employee> Employee1 = new TreeSet<Employee>();

            Employee1.add(e1);
            Employee1.add(e2);
            Employee1.add(e3);
            System.out.println(Employee1.size());

        }
    }
```

Comment: `In below created code`. I'm blind here.

Comment: Post your Employee class b/w TreeSet uses Comparable/Comparator

Comment: How is your code working ? or even compiling you have to do emp.getName and not emp.name .

Comment: What behavior do you want? Two entries or three entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are add something to TreeSet then compareTo method of class Employee is getting invoked and in `compareTo` method you are stating that if 2 names are equal then both objects are the same. Thats why TreeSet is adding only 2 objects `alok`and `vaibhav` . Moreover, currently you are comparing  string wrongly , in order to compare Strings use compareTo on String objects that compare objects based on natural ordering i.e. lexicographically

Comment: In order to compare strings for compareTo() why not use compareTo. If testing for equality use equals().

In Strings the compareTo method tests for lexical equality, including length of strings.

Comment: Please see the API on String compareTo: Compares two strings lexicographically. The comparison is based on the Unicode value of each character in the strings. The character sequence represented by this String object is compared lexicographically .... The result is a negative integer if this String object lexicographically precedes the argument string. The result is a positive integer if this String object lexicographically follows the argument string. The result is zero if the strings are equal; compareTo returns 0 exactly when the equals(Object) method would return true.

Comment: Thanks Don't know how it slipped from my mind , updated my answer

Comment: Excellent, please update the explanation as well. It is important that readers realize that Comparable<T> imposes an ordering and is not meant to infer equality. However natural orderings should be consistent with equals.

Answer (score 1):

In general sets you cannot have repetitions. Hence the size is two.

Since

```
 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Employee emp = (Employee) obj;  
           if (name.equals(emp. getName())) {  
               return true;  
           }
           return false;  
}
```

It checks only name even though the id is different it treats them as same objects.

Change it to

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if(obj instanceof this) {
           Employee emp = (Employee) obj;  
           if (name.equals(emp. getName()) && id == emp.getId()) {  
               return true;  
           }
           return false;  
       }
       return false;
    }
```

Also the code is wrong for

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Employee o) {
    if(this.name==o.name){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Change it to

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Employee o) {
    return name.compareTo(o.getName());
}
```

You cannot compare strings with == use .equals method.

Comment: Huh? compareTo and equality are entirely different concepts. Both code snippets are wrong. Also, if we are going to reduce this to a simple compareTo on a string why reinvent the wheel?

How about this?

  String a = "a";
  String b = "b";
   
  System.out.println(b.compareTo(b));
  System.out.println(b.compareTo(a));
  System.out.println(a.compareTo(b));
  
the output is very different than binary:
0
1
-1

Answer (score 0):

How could we get different results according to the set that is used? It's quite simple : the HashSet uses both equals and hashCode to check object equality. You've got 3 different ids, that's why you get 3 objects in your hashset.

On the other hand, the TreeSet will use your compareTo method (or a provided Comparator) to compare items and check equality. If you compareTo method uses names only to give its result, and knowing you have only 2 unique names, then the TreeSet will only have 2 elements (probably the last one will be discarded)

Answer (score 0):

Personally if I was going to base my comparison on a single string for insertion into the tree I would use what is already given to us:

```
public int compareTo(Employee o) {
    return this.name.compareTo(o.getName());
}
```

Not sure why this isn't the first choice? Am I missing something?

Given that, you probably need more than just the String, otherwise why have id's? I can't fathom two employee objects being the same if they have different id's (i.e.  if they have more than one ID, I would create an array of id's as names are not unique.)

Answer (score 0):

Both [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and [`Treeset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) doesn't allow duplicates.

The behavior is explained by understanding `How do you define a Duplicate!`

---

### HashSet

In case of `HashSet`,  the hashcodes for two objects are different even for same names, hence they are not considered duplicates.Unless you override `hashCode` and `equals` all the objects are considered distinct/unique

---

### TreeSet:

You are providing the definition of "Duplicate" by overriding `compareTo`. i.e. If the names are same then the Objects are same

To allow duplicates in your `TreeSet`, Change your `compareTo` to

```
@Override
  public int compareTo(Employee o) {
    if (this.name.equals(o.getName())) {
      return -1; //return 0 says that two objects are same 
    } else {
      return 1;  
    }
  }
```